# [UICollectionViewCell setItemDictionary:]: unrecognized selector sent to instance

Tags: objective-c, uiview, uicollectionview

I have a View Controller and in that View Controller, I have a button. On Click that button will slide in a view(ToolOptionsView). In this View I have a Collection View added but I am having this error

> [UICollectionViewCell setItemDictionary:]: unrecognized selector sent to instance

The following is my ToolOptionsView.m file-

```
#import "ToolOptionsView.h"

@interface ToolOptionsView ()

@property(nonatomic, strong) NSMutableArray *toolsList;
@property(nonatomic, strong) NSMutableDictionary *tools;

@end

@implementation ToolOptionsView

-(id)initWithFrame:(CGRect)frame{
    self=[super initWithFrame:frame];
    if(self){
        [self setToolsList];

        UICollectionViewFlowLayout *flowLayout = [[UICollectionViewFlowLayout alloc]init];
        flowLayout.scrollDirection = UICollectionViewScrollDirectionVertical;

        self.toolsCollectionView = [[UICollectionView alloc]initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0, 0, frame.size.width, frame.size.height) collectionViewLayout:flowLayout];
        self.toolsCollectionView.delegate = self;
        self.toolsCollectionView.dataSource=self;
        [self.toolsCollectionView registerClass:[UICollectionViewCell class] forCellWithReuseIdentifier:@"toolsCell"];

        [self addSubview:self.toolsCollectionView];

    }
    return self;
}


-(void)setToolsList{
    self.toolsList =[[NSMutableArray alloc]init];

    self.tools =[[NSMutableDictionary alloc]init];
    [self.tools setObject:@"Food" forKey:@"title"];
    [self.tools setObject:@"food.png" forKey:@"iconImage"];

    [self.toolsList addObject:self.tools];

    self.tools =[[NSMutableDictionary alloc]init];
    [self.tools setObject:@"Drinks" forKey:@"title"];
    [self.tools setObject:@"drinks.png" forKey:@"iconImage"];

    [self.toolsList addObject:self.tools];

    self.tools =[[NSMutableDictionary alloc]init];
   [self.tools setObject:@"Near By Restaurants" forKey:@"title"];
    [self.tools setObject:@"Restaurants.png" forKey:@"iconImage"];

    [self.toolsList addObject:self.tools];     
}

#pragma mark-
#pragma mark- UICollectionViewDatasource method

- (NSInteger)collectionView:(UICollectionView *)collectionView numberOfItemsInSection:(NSInteger)section{

   return [self.toolsList count];
}

- (UICollectionViewCell *)collectionView:(UICollectionView *)collectionView cellForItemAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath{

    MenuItemCollectionViewCell *cell = [collectionView dequeueReusableCellWithReuseIdentifier:@"toolsCell" forIndexPath:indexPath];
    NSMutableDictionary *dict = [self.toolsList objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];
    cell.itemDictionary = dict;
    return cell;
}
@end
```

and here is my MenuItemCollectionViewCell.h-

```
#import <UIKit/UIKit.h>
#import <QuartzCore/QuartzCore.h>
#import <CoreGraphics/CoreGraphics.h>

@interface MenuItemCollectionViewCell : UICollectionViewCell

@property(nonatomic, strong)  UIImageView *iconImageView;
@property(nonatomic, strong)  UILabel *iconLabel;

@property(nonatomic, strong) NSMutableDictionary *itemDictionary;

@end
```

and here is my `MenuItemCollectionViewCell.m` file-

```
#import "MenuItemCollectionViewCell.h"

@implementation MenuItemCollectionViewCell

-(void)awakeFromNib{
    self.iconImageView = [[UIImageView alloc]initWithFrame:CGRectMake(20, 20, self.bounds.size.width-40, self.bounds.size.height-40)];
    self.iconImageView.image = [UIImage imageNamed:[self.itemDictionary objectForKey:@"iconImage"]];
    [self addSubview:self.iconImageView];
    self.iconLabel = [[UILabel alloc]initWithFrame:CGRectMake(5, 23 + self.iconImageView.bounds.size.height, self.bounds.size.width-10 , 16)];
    self.iconLabel.text = [self.itemDictionary objectForKey:@"title"];
    [self addSubview:self.iconLabel];
}

@end
```

Comment: have you set up the identifier and class correctly? It looks like your are getting a generic `UICollectionViewCell` not a `MenuItemCollectionViewCell`.

Comment: Thank you, that was the issue. I registered my identifier for UiCollectionViewCell while, I should have done for MenuItemCollectionViewCell. Can you please post your suggestion as answer, so that I can accept it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In the line

```
[self.toolsCollectionView registerClass:[UICollectionViewCell class] forCellWithReuseIdentifier:@"toolsCell"];
```

you register the class `UICollectionViewCell` for the identifier but should actually register your custom class `MenuItemCollectionViewCell`:

```
[self.toolsCollectionView registerClass:[MenuItemCollectionViewCell class] forCellWithReuseIdentifier:@"toolsCell"];
```

Answer (score 0):

Most probably the cell returned from `dequeResuableCellWithIdentifier` Is not a `MenuItemCollectionViewCell`.
Put a breakpoint after that method and check what tipe of cell is returned in the debugger, just write `po cell.class`

Comment: no, it was, but the safer way would be to cast it anyways like - MenuItemCollectionViewCell  *cell = (MenuItemCollectionViewCell*)[collectionView dequeueReusableCellWithReuseIdentifier:@"toolsCell" forIndexPath:indexPath];